# During rollback, is lock escalation reversed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, locking, rollback

Generally, SQL Server will take locks during updates. It also supports [Lock Escalation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Lock escalation is the process of converting many fine-grain locks into fewer coarse-grain locks, reducing system overhead while increasing the probability of concurrency contention.

During a transaction ROLLBACK, does SQL Server de-escalate the locks, putting back the fine-grained locks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server does not de-escalate the lock.

I investigated using a "[Numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)" table with 100,000 rows. Empirically, updating 5,000 rows produced a corresponding number of RID locks in `sys.dm_tran_locks`. Updating a further 10,000 rows caused escalation to a single table lock.  This was consistently reproducible. To minimise the objects involved the table was a heap without indexes.

I used Extended Event tracing to capture `lock_acquired` and `lock_released` events. For ease of analysis I used separate traces during the UPDATE and ROLLBACK phases.

Two sessions (SSMS windows) were used - one for the DML statements and one for the trace DDL. I could not use as single session as I wanted to stop and start traces while the transaction is open and this is not permitted. The isolation level throughout is READCOMITTED.

The result of `select @@VERSION` is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (Intel X86)   Mar 26 2015 21:49:16   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

The steps taken were

1. Create and start the Acquire trace.

   ```
   CREATE EVENT SESSION DuringUpdate
   ON SERVER
   ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired,
   ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_released
   ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
       (SET filename = 'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringUpdate.xel',
        metadatafile = 'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringUpdate.xem')
   WITH(EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = NO_EVENT_LOSS,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 1 SECONDS
       );


   ALTER EVENT SESSION DuringUpdate
   ON SERVER
   STATE = start;
   ```
2. Begin a transaction and update 5000 rows.

   ```
   begin transaction;

   update dbo.Numbers
   set Number = Number
   where Number between 1 and 5000;
   ```
3. Update a further 10000 rows.

   ```
   update dbo.Numbers
   set Number = Number
   where Number between 5001 and 15000;
   ```
4. Stop the acquire trace.

   ```
   ALTER EVENT SESSION DuringUpdate
   ON SERVER
   STATE = stop;
   ```
5. Verify there are locks by querying `sys.dm_tran_locks` (2 - DB, table).
6. Create and start the Release trace.

   ```
   CREATE EVENT SESSION DuringRollback
   ON SERVER
   ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_acquired,
   ADD EVENT sqlserver.lock_released
   ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
       (SET filename = 'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringRollback.xel', 
            metadatafile = 'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringRollback.xem')
   WITH(EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = NO_EVENT_LOSS,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 1 SECONDS
       );


   ALTER EVENT SESSION DuringRollback
   ON SERVER
   STATE = start;
   ```
7. Roll back the transaction.

   ```
   rollback;
   ```
8. Stop the Release trace.

   ```
   ALTER EVENT SESSION DuringRollback
   ON SERVER
   STATE = stop;
   ```
9. Tidy up

   ```
   DROP EVENT SESSION DuringUpdate
   ON SERVER;

   DROP EVENT SESSION DuringRollback
   ON SERVER;
   ```

If lock de-escalation occurred I would expect complete symmetry in the two trace files - every lock acquired during UPDATE, and the escalation, would have a corresponding release during ROLLBACK. What I observed:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as DuringUpdate
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(
    'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringUpdate*.xel', 
    'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringUpdate*.xem', null, null);

SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as DuringRollback
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(
    'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringRollback*.xel', 
    'c:\temp\LockRollback\DuringRollback*.xem', null, null);
```

was 383,889 rows and 166 rows respectively. Examining the event XML for the rollback file there is only one event relating to RIDs, PAGEs or OBJECTS - the release of an X lock on the table. I conclude from this that locks were not de-escalated during rollback.

This echos the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for rolling back to a named savepoint:

> A ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement specifying a savepoint_name releases any locks that are acquired beyond the savepoint, **with the exception of escalations** and conversions. These locks are not released, and they are not converted back to their previous lock mode.